# Sum of primes to the power of themselves, plus one

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Which primes $p$ and $q$ have the property that $p^p + q^q + 1$ is divisible by $pq$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given primes $p$ and $q$, the number $p^p+q^q+1$ is divisible by $pq$ if and only if
$$p^p\equiv-1\pmod{q}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad q^q\equiv-1\pmod{p}.$$
In particular $p\neq q$, and without loss of generality $p<q$. Then the first congruence shows that the multiplicative group $(\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$ contains an element of order $p$, so in particular $p$ divides $q-1$. This means $q\equiv1\pmod{p}$, and so $q^q\equiv1\pmod{p}$. Then the second congruence shows that $-1\equiv1\pmod{p}$ and hence that $p=2$. Then the first congruence tells us that $4\equiv-1\pmod{q}$, so $q=5$. And indeed $2\times5=10$ divides
$$2^2+5^5+1=4+3125+1=3130.$$